# AngularJS hide textbox after sucess response

Tags: angularjs

I enable a textbox if the user clicks the edit button. This is working fine:

**my.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in Value" >
    <td>
        <span ng-show="!data.edit">{{data.question}}</span>
        <input ng-show="data.edit" type="text" ng-model="data.question" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="editUtterance(data)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="save(data)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Save</button></td>
</tr>
```

**myscript.js**

```
$scope.editUtterance = function(data){
                        //alert(data.question); 
                        data.edit = true;
                        //console.log(data.edit);
                    }
                    $scope.updateModalUtterance = function(data){
                        //alert(data.id); 
                        $scope.id = data.id;
                        alert($scope.id);
                        data.edit = true;
                        var data = {
                            question: data.question
                        }
                        $http({
                        method: 'PATCH', 
                        url:'/api/url/'+$scope.id,
                        params:data,
                            }).then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            $scope.edit = 'false';                            
                            console.log($scope.edit);
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log(response); 
                        });
                    }
```

After the success response I am trying to hide the textbox, but it's not hiding.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: well, you have `data.edit` most places but in your response, you switched to `$scope.edit` (not the same property).  Seems like a typo.  also, you seem to be re-declaring your data in your function;  I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: In addition, setting a variable to the string `'false'` in javascript will actually result in it being truthy which is probably not the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the function, create a variable

```
$scope.textVisi=true;
```

and after success response make it as `false` like below.

```
    //your code
    .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response.data);
         $scope.textVisi = false;                          
         console.log($scope.edit);
    });
```

and use this variable in `ng-if` on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Pass  $index of loop in function editUtterance in html

```
<td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="editUtterance(data, $index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Edit</button></td>
```

and change controller function like :

```
$scope.editUtterance = function(data, _idx){
                        //alert(data.question); 
                        $scope.Value[_idx]['edit'] = true; // <=============Change this line and update other places similarly
                        //console.log(data.edit);
                    }
                    $scope.updateModalUtterance = function(data){
                        //alert(data.id); 
                        $scope.id = data.id;
                        alert($scope.id);
                        $scope.Value[_idx]['edit'] = true;
                        var data = {
                            question: data.question
                        }
                        $http({
                        method: 'PATCH', 
                        url:'/api/url/'+$scope.id,
                        params:data,
                            }).then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            $scope.Value[_idx]['edit'] = false;                           
                            console.log($scope.edit);
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log(response); 
                        });
                    }
```

Hopefully, this helps you.

Comment: i got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: $scope.Value  Where is Value is defined in same controller or somewhere else

Comment: No I din't define any where